# How can I automatically detect frequent actions and create keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, automation

Automating what you do most is in my opinion one of the best ways to increase productivity and ease your life.

How can I automatically detect what I do most and have my computer flag it to me, then offer to create a keyboard shortcut?

Is that even possible?

This sounds ambitious, but hey it's 2017 and M. Zuckerberg built Jarvis (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvimBPJ3XGQ) so I'm certain that there is a way.

(I'm using osx)

Comment: It may be best advised to move this to apple.stackexchange.com as it may have better and previous answers.

Comment: Have you done any research on your idea? If yes, please edit your question with details. Are you using OS X or macOS?